# jQuery custom functions and passing parameters to them

Tags: jquery

I have a row of images, and when one of the images is clicked it expands while also shrinking any other image that may be enlarged. If you click on the enlarged image, it just shrinks itself.

I'm receiving a 'shrink is not defined' error message. Thanks in advance.

```
        $.fn.grow = function(size,rate) {
            $(this).addClass('click').animate({'height': size}, rate);
        }
        $.fn.shrink = function(size,rate) {
            $('img').removeClass('click').animate({'height': size}, rate);
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#gallery img').click(function() {
                var $this = $(this);
                ($this.hasClass('click')) ? $this.shrink('139', '200') : $this.shrink('139', '200').grow('700', '200');
            });
        });
```

Comment: Why do you declare: var $this = $(this);
I'd say that confuzes JQuery cuz ur using the $ selector in a variable name. I am not 100% sure if that is allowed and if that is the cause. But try either just using $(this), or declare your variable differently.. like  var me = $(this);

Comment: @Jules Variables with a leading `$` are valid in JavaScript.

Comment: And actually preferred by many as an indicator that the variable is in fact a jQuery object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I received a different exception...

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'grow' of undefined

You are attempting to chain the methods (or *use the cascade* if you like Crockfordian terms), but neither of your custom functions returns a jQuery object.

You need to make them `return` something, generally `this`. In a jQuery custom function, `this` is already a jQuery object, so there is no need to wrap it again.

Comment: +1, although for the `shrink` method, I think you'd want to return `this` so that the chaining continues on the original element. [Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/2QD3t/).

Comment: ...also, the `grow` method can just do `this.addClass('click')`. No need to wrap it as in the question. (For OP's sake. I know you know that.) ;o)

Answer (score 0):

If you use $.fn.extend like that:

```
$.fn.extend({
    shrink: function() {$(this).doSth()},
    grow: function() {$(this).doSth()}
});
```

You will be able to apply your shrink and grow methods to any jQuery wrapped object eg

```
$('img').shrink();
```

Hope it helps